# Field Arrangement in ADF panelFormLayout

Tags: oracle-adf

When I am putting my fields in panelFormLayout ,It is showing elemnts in below format

```
1         4
2         5
3         6
```

But I want the fields should be in below format

```
1         2
3         4
5         6
```

Can some one point the correct way to do this.
Code

```xml
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" fieldWidth="150" labelWidth="150" labelAlignment="start" rows="3" maxColumns="2">
    <af:inputText label="1" id="it1"/>
    <af:inputText label="2" id="it2"/>
    <af:inputText label="3" id="it2"/>
    <af:inputText label="4" id="it2"/>
    <af:inputText label="5" id="it2"/>
    <af:inputText label="6" id="it2"/>
</af:panelFormLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the `inputText` fields by row, using one `panelFormLayout` per row:

```xml
<af:group id="g1">

    <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl21" rows="1" maxColumns="2"
                        labelAlignment="start" fieldWidth="150"
                        labelWidth="150">
        <af:inputText label="first" id="it21"/>
        <af:inputText label="second" id="it23"/>
    </af:panelFormLayout>

    <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl22" rows="1" maxColumns="2"
                        labelAlignment="start" fieldWidth="150"
                        labelWidth="150">
        <af:inputText label="third" id="it25"/>
        <af:inputText label="fourth" id="it22"/>
    </af:panelFormLayout>

    <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl23" rows="1" maxColumns="2"
                        labelAlignment="start" fieldWidth="150"
                        labelWidth="150">
        <af:inputText label="fifth" id="it24"/>
        <af:inputText label="sixth" id="it26"/>
    </af:panelFormLayout>

</af:group>
```

[image]

For a proper vertical alignment of the labels and the input fields, it is just necessary to set the `fieldWidth` and the `labelWidth` to reasonable values, but you did this already in your code.

See also [Controlling tab order in an ADF Form](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/controlling_tab_order_in_an_ad).